# Protecting "back-end" angular source files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, go

I have a Angular system that solely talks with my Go back-end and with Gorilla I take care of my sessions for login.

I started working on my admin environment, but I wondered what would be best practice for protecting the angular code for it. It's not really a problem for security because even the admin code will just have logic, and not dangerous data, still I prefer to not have it open to just anyone in the world.

I was thinking of doing the following;

I have a `mux` router that catches all my resource calls (deployment with Yeoman) and I was wondering that I would make 3 exceptions there for `images/admin`, `scripts/admin` and `styles/admin`. These paths can then only be served if you have a valid session active. Otherwise throwing a 401 header.

Would this be a good solution or is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You can to force https, and use basic auth. We implement this tech here, and it's a very efficient manner. (A sample: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx )

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo but at some point you need to check the authorization. Whatever method you put in place to do the authroization+file serving, it end up to be some (minimal) application code and then offloading the serving to something more efficient, linke Nginx.

Comment: "Protect" them from what? What is your threat model?

Comment: @rewritten Here we send on basic auth a token (to identify the user) and the password encoded with sha256. Remember, using https... and then, on server, it's only a select to validate the user... it's can be implemented directly on nginx... and the nginx will be the "firewall" for auth, and the back server doesn't needs any auth rules, if he's inaccessible externally.

Comment: I'd strongly advise not to do database access from Nginx and VERY STRONGLY advide not to distribute authentication and authorization code in several places. The OP asked for a way to protect admin-related assets, so it's a matter of authorization (what a specific user *can* do), so it's in the realm of their app business logic. What if the definition of 'admin' changes? What if it's not in a SQL database anymore? (LDAP access, or just data stored in a session in a redis instance) You can't expect that your authorization works for long  if it's sparse in several seemingly unrelated places.

Comment: @NickJohnson good catch.

Comment: I don't use Nginx or Apache. I serve everything solely HTTPS with a strict routing combined with file-serving, custom tailored with a final catchAll, which prevents any directory listing or serving of paths/subpaths that I wouldn't want to be served. @NickJohnson as I stated it's not really to "protect", but more to not have them open by default. So only the select few that have credentials to get into the admin-environment get the files served. This is more a convenience question than one of security.

Comment: Wrap the admin static handler with some auth middleware that checks for a Bearer Token in the Authorization header, else returns a 401. You should, however, operate under the model that the static assets may be accessed: relying on them to be protected is not a good plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a valid (and preferably authorized) session to get some static assets (being them JS code, stylesheets, images...), you need to pass through the application, the stack you use is not relevant at all.

What I'd do is to point the resource to something controlled by your application, and then return either a 401 or an empty response with a `X-Sendfile` or `X-Accel-Redirect` header so the actual serving is offloaded to whatever reverse proxy you have in place.

Comment: I don't use any standard technology and, as stated in my comment in my question, serve everything myself. This means I can easily achieve filtering out the paths that I want to not be serve-able to unauthorized users. I'm just curious how other people approached this and what would be pros and cons of different solutions. I was indeed thinking of just bouncing 401's on non-authorized users that still try to access these paths. Maybe even just 404, but it might not be the most pretty one.

Comment: I understand that your application serves HTTP directly (as in fact most web apps do). In any case (even if it's off topic) i'd always put a reverse proxy in front of anything written by myself, just in case; as an example, with a reverse proxy you han handle downtime much more gracefully. And if some work can be offloaded to it, much better!

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration @rewritten I'll take that into consideration :)